# Opening Word from Excel using VBA – Several errors

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ms-word

I am currently trying to open Microsoft Word from Microsoft Excel using VBA. I found these resources online:

- [Official Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/excel/concepts/working-with-other-applications/exporting-a-table-to-a-word-document)
- [Microsoft Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-auto-populate-and-create-a-word-document/c7bd5409-6b56-4381-950b-62f8593d3bba)

Based on them, I came up with the following code:

---

### Code 1

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

#### Running the code with Word already open

Excel stops responding.

#### Running the code with Word closed

Word opens, but Excel gives me the error `Out of memory` or `Automation error` and `wordApp` is not defined.

---

### Code 2

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Set wordApp = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
```

#### Running the code with Word already open

Excel throws the error `Out of memory` and `wordApp` is not defined.

#### Running the code with Word closed

Excel throws the error `ActiveX component can't create object or return reference to this object` and `wordApp` is not defined.

---

### System information

OS: macOS Mojave (10.14.6)

Excel and Word Version: 16.36

References in Excel:

```
Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library, Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation
```

---

### Conclusion

These errors are quite confusing and I could not fix them by reading Microsoft's error pages. For instance, I continuously get the error `Out of memory` (see above), although I have around 10 GB of free RAM space. How can I get this to work both on my machine (see above) as well as any other machine reliably?

Answer (score 1):

Combining your both approaches in only one will look like this, and it shouldn't return any error.

If the error still persists, it is not connected to the code itself...
Only reference to `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library` necessary.

```
Sub openWordApp()
  Dim wordApp As Word.Application

  On Error Resume Next
   Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
      Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
   wordApp.Visible = True
   Debug.Print wordApp.Documents.count
End Sub
```

Please, also check if not multiple Word sessions are open... Maybe you checked the code many times with Word session `Visible = False` and there still are a lot of such sessions open. Just maybe, but it would be good to check it.

Comment: I still get an error on the line `Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`. It reads `Runtime error: Out of memory` no matter whether Word was open before or not. If this error is not related to the code as you stated, what is it related to then?

Comment: @Paul: Did you also check how many Word sessions are open in the moment you try the code? I mean, not visible sessions. I do not work on MAC, but I suppose that it is a kind of `Task Manager` able to show you all open processes. `Activity Monitor` I think...

Comment: When I run your code, Word actually opens and is focussed, but the `wordApp` object is still not defined then for further use. By the way, I tried your code again and now I get an `Automation Error` on the same line...

Comment: @Paul: Why do you say "it is  not defined"? Does  `Debug.Print wordApp.Documents.count` return an error? If not, it is well defined (when it works...), even if it returns zero for the new created session. Do you need the object to be used after this piece of code works? If yes, you must declare the variable at module level (on top of module code - declarations part). A Sub variable life is as the sub works. It cannot be used in another sub. But you still did not say anything about your Word open sessions... Did you check this aspect?

Comment: @Paul: If you do not use `wordApp.Quit`, it stays open until you manually (or protramatically) quit...

Comment: When I run the code once, one Word session appears on my Mac's Activity Monitor. However, when I then run the code another time, this Word session is just brought to the front. There is never more than one active Word session!

`Debug.Print wordApp.Documents.count` is never even reached, because `Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` throws an error before.

Comment: Since you try using my code, it activates the session you can see. But, if you played many times with your code trying to `CreateObject`, you could create many (hidden) Word sessions, which still exists... Please forget about 'active Word session` and scroll down to see if there ar not a lot of other Word open sessions between existing processes...

Comment: @Paul: Please refresh the page, close the Word active session and run my updated code line by line. From VBE press F8 to run the code line by line. If the code does not go inside `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` ... `End If', this means that another Word open session has been found and it will be make visible... Do you see a Word session discovered by your code?

Comment: The code always goes inside the if statement, even if I completely quit Word before. Unfortunately, on my Mac I cannot see different sessions of an Application. I just see each application running once. Now, excel gives me an error for `wordApp.Visible = True` saying `Object variable or With block variable not set`. In my understanding, that means that `wordApp` is undefined.

Comment: Your understanding is correct... I cannot reproduce your error, so I don't know I can help. I will delete my answer in some minutes. I would suggest you to use a code like mine, which can not allow more sessions open. For now, I would suggest you to close excel, close unnecessary processes/applications and try again.

Comment: I will try to do so! Thank you for your time!